# Best Horror Film Visual+Sound Combination?

Tags: halloween, favorite, design

I hope everyone had a safe and Happy Halloween.

Ok, I had to ask, it being Halloween and all,

What's your favorite Horror Film Visual+Sound combination?

I know it's probably been asked before on this site "What's your favorite Horror sound design?", but I wanted to know in terms of Randy Thom's article about designing a movie for sound, what movie has the best instance of this?

My vote would be for The Ring. Or, Jaws, because in Jaws, you hardly see the killer, just sounds - 2 notes of music!

Happy Halloween!

Comment: Do you mean Ringu? or the americanised version?

Comment: @Tim I mean the Americanised version. I'm too scared to watch the original. It's quite good, isn't it? That's what I've heard.

Answer (score 2):

The Shining - the boy riding his trike down those hallways, stopping at the door & those creepy twins.... what a genius Kubrick was

Comment: GREAT ANSWER! I noticed the boy on the tricycle, too. The carpet and wood tradeoffs - very nice!!!

Comment: beautiful steadicam work too

Answer (score 1):

Alien (if it counts as a horror film)

The scene where Brett gets killed. The sounds of the bowels of the ship mixed with the rattling chains really create a majestic suspense.

Comment: Yeah - +1! Great scene.

Answer (score 1):

"The Changeling" (1980 wt. George C. Scott, not the Angelina Jolie movie) and the Original 1963 "The Haunting"... both eschew fancy visual FX in favour of things that go "bump" in the night.

Check out the scene in "The Changeling" where George C. Scott plays back the tape of music he was composing and hears the child's voice. Still creeps me out!

And on a more modern note, the delightfully cheesy remake of "13 Ghosts"(2001) - love the sounds of that.

Comment: Great ideas. I'll have to check the original Changeling out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not for the fear aspect, but anything to do with Jason Voorhees.  His tell-tale delayed noise causes a mix of excitement and fear in almost everyone I know, and it wouldn't be Halloween without at least one Jason movie.